# Is it possible to integrate Hubspot with Salesforce without enabling 'Modify Metadata through Metadata API'?

Tags: api, security, salesforce, hubspot

I'm currently exploring the integration between HubSpot and Salesforce (SFDC) using the native connector. While setting up a custom profile to grant permissions, I've encountered a security concern regarding enabling the "Modify Metadata through Metadata API" function. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone has successfully implemented a workaround for this issue.

My hesitation stems from the potential security implications that enabling this function might have. As per the HubSpot website, they state, "Without this permission, you MAY encounter limitations or be unable to perform certain tasks." However, I'm seeking further insights into the exact limitations that could arise if this permission is not enabled. Turning it off seems to completely prevent the the integration from working.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Enabling the  "Modify Metadata through Metadata API" will fix the issue in Sandbox environment, but turning it off seems to completely prevent the the integration from working.